# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fakedata

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

class JdbcTrail{
public static void main(String [] args){
 try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fakedata", "root", "root"))
{
boolean isValid = conn.isValid(0);
System.out.println("connection status :" + isValid);
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

I am trying to connect with my database, but every time it throws this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fakedata
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at JdbcTrail.main(JdbcTrail.java:8)
```

I am writing this code in notepad

Comment: you need to add jdbc jar to your classpath when you run the program

Comment: but how can I add a jar file as I am writing this code on notepad, yes we can do it in an IDE like eclipse but I am desperate to do it on notepad ?

Comment: jar file is added at run time by specifying `-classpath` arg to java.exe

Comment: yeah, how can i add a classpath during runtime when I am running the program in my command shell.

Comment: there is no way to add jar file during source code writeup. no matter what tool is used for writing. IDE just makes it easier to construct the runtime command